# forge.facebook.authorize returning incorrect Facebook token expiry time

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk, trigger.io, parse-platform

I've been using `forge.facebook.authorize()` successfully for several months in my app to get FB auth tokens.

However since a certain point last week I've been unable to validate any of the tokens it's been returning, due to an incorrect expiry time, and thus unable to sign-up or log-in any Facebook users since.

**I must make clear that none of my code changed** - this FB login was working fine previously and then suddenly stopped and hasn't since. A deployed live app suddenly stopped letting users log in with Facebook.

reponse from forge.facebook.authorize:

```
[FORGE] '"successfully authorized with FB", 

{"access_token":"....","access_expires":1367922592459}'
```

I then turn the expiry seconds into a JS date object with this function:

```
function toDateTime(secs) {
    var t = new Date();
    t.setSeconds(secs * -1);
    return t;
}

toDateTime(1367922592459);
> Sun Jun 11 -41335 12:22:41 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

See here the year is showing something crazy, definitely before Facebook was invented.

So anyway, then my code passes the FB auth data to Parse.com to log in a user, and Parse.com obviously throws it back for having an invalid expiry time.

The problem is occurring on iOS and Android apps built with trigger.io v1.4.29 and v1.4.33

Note: I have a working FB javascript login on my webpage (http://wewana.com/) which is connecting to the same Facebook app and the same Parse.com application. This page is not exhibiting any problems, so it seems the FB app is fine.

Comment: After some rubber-duck-debugging I worked something out. It looks like the expiry date is being returned in milliseconds and not seconds. Eg: var d2 = new Date(0); d2.setUTCSeconds(1367922592459/1000); > Tue May 07 2013 11:29:52 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)

Comment: I'm confused: in your comment you're using new Date(0) and not multiplying by -1 -- this looks right and I'd expect that to work. In your question (and your live apps), you're using new Date() and multiplying by -1. I don't see how that could work, whether access_expires was in milliseconds or not... Are you sure you've not pushed out broken JS (using Reload, for example?)

Comment: The upshot is pretty much that - the toDateTime() function was broken, but Parse.com were accepting invalid expiry dates - so users we getting logged in and we never saw a problem with toDateTime(). Parse fixed their bug and then this issue became apparent. Sent you a mail this morning with the deets, did you get it? Perhaps I'm in your spam list now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date(1367922592459);
```

There you go, simple and easy.

(Since JavaScript handles Date in milliseconds, there’s no need to do `/1000` or something.)

Answer (score 2):

```
t.setSeconds(secs * -1);
```

Are you intentionally multiplying by `-1`? I'm not seeing why this could be expected to work.

Comment: Yes, that was deliberate. Although right now I can't remember exactly why - really could have done with a code comment there. Also I may have just worked something out, pls see my comment on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

tldr;
I was incorrectly processing the expiry timestamps as seconds. Processing them as milliseconds fixes the issue. Clearly there was an issue with `toDateTime()`

Full version:
For some time parse.com has been accepting invalid FB expiry dates. As users were getting logged in fine we did not know there was a problem. 
Recently parse changed something so they error on invalid dates, causing our login to break.

Our function that translated seconds into a JS date object needed to be changed to convert based on milliseconds.

New working function:

```
function toDateTime(secs) {
    var t = new Date(0);
    t.setUTCSeconds(secs / 1000);
    return t;
}
```